# SOIL Image size

Tags: c++, opengl, soil

Can I somehow get size of an image (of any SOIL supports)?

I know that there are different headers in image files which define these sizes. But is there any function from SOIL to get image size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SOIL_load_image()` will populate the width/height parameters with the dimensions of the image, though it does a full load of the image to do so:

```
/**
    Loads an image from disk into an array of unsigned chars.
    Note that *channels return the original channel count of the
    image.  If force_channels was other than SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
    the resulting image has force_channels, but *channels may be
    different (if the original image had a different channel
    count).
    \return 0 if failed, otherwise returns 1
**/
unsigned char*
    SOIL_load_image
    (
        const char *filename,
        int *width, int *height, int *channels,
        int force_channels
    );
```

The underlying `stb_image.h` [has routines](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h#L422) that don't load the full image:

```
// get image dimensions & components without fully decoding
STBIDEF int      stbi_info_from_memory(stbi_uc const *buffer, int len, int *x, int *y, int *comp);
STBIDEF int      stbi_info_from_callbacks(stbi_io_callbacks const *clbk, void *user, int *x, int *y, int *comp);
STBIDEF int      stbi_is_16_bit_from_memory(stbi_uc const *buffer, int len);
STBIDEF int      stbi_is_16_bit_from_callbacks(stbi_io_callbacks const *clbk, void *user);

#ifndef STBI_NO_STDIO
STBIDEF int      stbi_info               (char const *filename,     int *x, int *y, int *comp);
STBIDEF int      stbi_info_from_file     (FILE *f,                  int *x, int *y, int *comp);
STBIDEF int      stbi_is_16_bit          (char const *filename);
STBIDEF int      stbi_is_16_bit_from_file(FILE *f);
#endif
```